# Umbraco public site says "This webpage is not available"

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

I have downloaded Umbraco 7.2.1 and compiled it and published it. It's working fine in local, but when I upload it to my hosting smarterasp the admin site works fine but public site says this webpage is not available. The database for Umbraco is in SQL.

*(both URLs have expired, and are now removed)*

When you click on admin site you will see login page while public site will not be loaded.

Comment: Have you made sure to republish all items after you deployed the website to the server? You can do it by going to this url on your site: /Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

Comment: yes i already did that. i am providing test env login details . you may try with login: test password: test@123 on url: tasminpatel-001-site4.smarterasp.net/umbraco

Comment: I've voted to close, as this question is dependent on URLs that have since expired. Please try to make your questions as self-contained as possible. That means, if you can, not adding links to your site on the internet - use a JS Fiddle or some live runner if necessary, but put the code into the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a hostname on the node that will serve as your frontpage.

Right click on a node, select "Manage hostnames", add the domain name (in your case tasminpatel-001-site4.smarterasp.net) and that should be it.

[image]

Comment: I did what you said but this has not helped me. you may try with login: test password: test@123 on url: http://tasminpatel-001-site4.smarterasp.net/umbraco

Comment: I just checked, the url is now hitting the template but you have an issue somewhere else, most likely with content compression - try to disable dynamic compression on IIS, from what I see, there could be the problem.

Comment: i would like to know why compression did not work with umbraco?

Comment: It is probably caused by CliendDepenendcy. You can read more about it [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/13525-Client-Dependency-Module-playing-havoc-with-gzip-content-compression). There is also a security issue with ClientDependency so make sure to do what is explained [here](http://umbraco.com/39310). And change the password if you haven't changed it already :)